# Telegram html5 game return blank page

Tags: javascript, telegram

When using telegram html5 game in telegram app I get blank page(http or https are the same).
this error is only on android, in Iphone it works normally
who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that SSL is not supported by webview in android. solution: Choose SSL that webview supports and it works!